# How use iOS AppTrackingTransparency.ATTrackingManager from cross-platform PCL?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So yesterday this line:

```
          ATTrackingManager.RequestTrackingAuthorization((status) => {
                     if (status == ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
                     {
                     }
```

was working code (in my cross-platform Xamarin.Forms PCL).
Today xamarin.ios received an update.

In the PCL project, the tracking manager is not found anymore. Intellisense doesnt know what it is anymore and I cannot debug the app.

It is recognized in the xamarin.ios project, but I need to access it from my PCL.

Anyone having the same issue and / or has already found a solution?

How can I rollback to xamarin.ios before the one I received today?

Comment: you title says "Xamarin.Forms" but this appears to be an iOS specific question, and your title also specficially says "apptrackingtransparancy" but that is not in your question anywhere.  What specific class is causing the problem?

Comment: it is a class referable to from PCL wich is a xamarin.forms project. But this app tracking tranparency thing is only needed for ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to rollback. As a test, I updated

- Visual Studio (which also updated Xamarin.iOS).
- XCode to 14.5.1.

Then I added a line of code to an existing Xamarin Forms solution, that referenced `AppTrackingTransparency.ATTrackingManager`. This was recognized as valid code. I Also tried just `ATTrackingManager`, and Intellisense correctly told me I needed `using AppTrackingTransparency`.

So its there now.

That namespace+classname is specific to iOS, so must be referenced from the iOS-specific project. (If it previously was referenceable in the PCL, that was probably a bug that has since been corrected; such code would break on any other platform.)

---

First step:

In your iOS project, write code that references that class.

---

Second step:

You need to know how to use your custom iOS code from the cross-platform Xamarin Forms PCL.

I won't repeat that here - there are multiple Q&As on that topic.
google "stackoverflow xamarin forms call platform specific code".

Comment: How can I update everything again?

I tried the rest already, it is just not found anymore.

Comment: Also, I relized its found in ioS project, but not pcl, where i need it...

Comment: @innom - Given that you are able to access it in iOS project, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh boy, that is such a good workaround. I ended up using an interface and the dependencyservice. clean and easy! thank you!!!